# Rewrite a nested flatmap expression with an if and else clause to a for comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

Consider the following nested flatmap structure:

```
val isValid: F[Boolean] = userRepository.isValid(username, password)

isValid.flatMap(valid =>
  if (valid) {
    userRepository.getClaims(username).flatMap(claims => {
      val token = JWTRefreshService.createToken(claims)
      Created(token)
    }
   )
  } else {
      Unauthorized(headers.`WWW-Authenticate`(NonEmptyList.of(Challenge(scheme = "Bearer", realm =
      "Access to authorize a request"))))
    }
  )
```

where `F` is `F[_] : Sync`.

How can i rewrite this structure into a for-comprehension. I cant figure out how to rewrite the if else clause without creating a nested for-comprehension.

Comment: Since you're scoping `F` to `Sync`, there's very little you could do here.

Comment: okay so i need to write a nested for comprehension or a for comprehension containing a flatmap?

Comment: Can you please create [mcve]? What is `userRepository.getClaims` and its return type? What is `JWTRefreshService.createToken` and its return type?

Comment: I can create one but not in the next 8 hours :(

Comment: But the signatures are as followed:

`def createToken(claims: List[String]): F[String]` where `F` is `F[_]`

and

`def getClaims(username: String): F[List[String]]`  where `F` is also `F[_]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
for {
  isValid <- userRepository.isValid(username, password)
  validation <- if (isValid) createToken(username)
                else
                  Unauthorized(
                    headers.`WWW-Authenticate`(
                      NonEmptyList.of(Challenge(scheme = "Bearer", realm = "Access to authorize a request"))
                  )
                )
} yield validation

def createToken[F: Sync](username: String): F[YourADT] = for {
  claims <- userRepository.getClaims(username)
  token  <- JWTRefreshService.createToken(claims)
} yield Created(token)
```